# Show another div on multiple elements on click

Tags: jquery

I'm working with portfolio (isotope) and I want to do next:

When I click on some category items are filtered but I want to mark (put tag on some elements) some elements with another div. And when i click on another category items will be filtered and new elements will have the same div as previous.

```
<ul> 
<li><a href="#" class="selected" data-filter="*">All</a></li> 
<li><a class="" href="#" data-filter=".category1">category1</a></li>
 <li><a class="" href="#" data-filter=".category2">category2</a></li>
 <li><a class="" href="#" data-filter=".category3">category3</a></li>
 <li><a class="" href="#" data-filter=".category4">category4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Each category have few elements like this

```
<figure class="portfolio-item four columns entry category1 category2 -item"> 
<div class="img-item"> 
<a href="link.html" >
 <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="" />
<span class="zoomex">&nbsp;</span>
</a>
 </div>
 <figcaption>
<h4>
<a href="link.html">Name</a>
</h4>
</figcaption>
 </figure>
```

so I want to do next - let's say you click category 4. All items from this category are shown but i want first three to have star (image of star) on it. Now, let's say you click category 2, items from category two are shown but first three items from this category have star on it

Answer (score 0):

If your divs are constant , add a `class` to the same set of elements ( ie items of the same group) , use the `style="display:none"` for all your items initially , when a category is selected switch that `class` to `display:block` , this way you can have the different items in different categories displayed in your div.

I am assuming you get all the elements first , if not and you are making ajax calls you can dynamically allocate a class to the search results